# How does threejs place a mesh into the scene without any coordinates given?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have began to create a personal project by using threejs and I would like someone to explain how threejs `add` method works when adding to the scene.

For example, from a [small example](https://medium.com/@necsoft/three-js-101-hello-world-part-1-443207b1ebe1), a scene is defined and a camera is created while specifying the near and far plane from the units 0.1 to 1000. That is all that is defined into the world and the mesh is added into the scene by calling `scene.add(cube)`.

How is the cube added into the scene without any coordinates given?

On this note, does anybody have a good link to explain the coordinate systems used for threejs/opengl? Many thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of defaults associated with threejs objects, and position is just one of them, defaulting to (0,0,0), per https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.position.

Comment: @JonTrent Wouldn't (0,0,0) be out of sight due to the near plane being 0.1?

Comment: @JonTrent The camera Z position seems to be assigned to 5 aswell.

Comment: The camera looks along the negative z-axis by default. So when it has the position `(0,0,5)`, it can perfectly see the cube with the mentioned `near/far` configuration.

Comment: @JDoe, with respect to a good link to explain the coordinate system, see https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/first-scene/, which covers that and much more.

Comment: @JonTrent Can you please write your responses into an answer so it can be accepted, and the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to dipping the toe into the pool of threejs, a few resources that I found helpful getting started were https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/first-scene/ and https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.

In the case of the latter, https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.position specifies the defaults when placing an object into the scene.

Hope this helps.